# Number of literals in FDNF

Tags: logic

I have this question. I haven't learn it and haven't found an answer.
Can you help me?

Formula $F$ full disjunctive normal form consists of $n$ different clauses and it has $m$ literals. How to calculate, on how much values formula $\lnot F$  is negative?

I hope you understand my question!

Thank you!

Comment: Not clear... "how much values formula ¬F is negative?" ?

Comment: On how many valuation formula ¬F is false?